# Invalid format string in Python

Tags: python, string

I get the invalid format string error when I try to run the below code (last line), not sure where I am missing the point:

```
  import datetime
  DAYS = 2
  SINCE = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=DAYS)
  params = "?fields=feed.since(" + SINCE.strftime("%s") + ").limit(1),name,updated_time&amp;"
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated !!

Comment: Works fine for me, both in 2 and in 3.

Comment: Are you passing 'params' into a SQL query?

Comment: My python version is 3.6.1 and Anaconda version is 4.4.0 (64 bit)

Comment: @Thomas it doesn't work for me in Python 2. It requires "s" to be capitalised in order to get units of seconds. Otherwise it throws `ValueError: Invalid format string`

Comment: @roganjosh Interesting. I guess Python (on Linux) just passes it on to `strftime` from libc, which _does_ have `%s`. But maybe on other platforms it's emulated without `%s` support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use "%S" because "%s" is not defined in the method you called : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.strftime

```
import datetime
DAYS = 2
SINCE = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=DAYS)
params = "?fields=feed.since(" + SINCE.strftime("%S") + ").limit(1),name,updated_time&amp;"
```

You should add what format you need for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which format suits you, but if you need timestamp use:

```
int(time.mktime(SINCE.timetuple()))
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me (Python 2.7). If it is part of a query and it is failing on that part, maybe you can use another date format like:

`params = "?fields=feed.since(" + SINCE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ").limit(1),name,updated_time&amp;"`

Please note that capital "S", will give you the seconds of that datetime object.

Comment: We are discussing your first point in comments under the main question. It doesn't work in Python 2.7 on Windows, but it seems it does work on Linux.

Comment: Well then SINCE.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") should work fine in the query. It is a useful workaround.